# The off button eliminated in the right corner of above in ubuntu 12.04 (Unity)

Tags: unity, 12.04

I always have used unity and I have never had any problem, but now that I reinstated ubuntu 12.04, but when it had stopped using her on having extinguished it I saw that unity's off button was not, it is possible to extinguish of other forms like that that I her restarted to see if it was corrected but till now I continue with the same problem, some programs that I installed were ubuntu tweak and the interior decorator of windows emerald, not if the problem is for one of these things. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-session
sudo apt-get install indicator-session
```

And then restart you system!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug where if you use a theme other than Ambiance or Radiance, the system status menu in the top right won't show.

I believe it is fixed if you install gnome-icon-theme-full. Log out and then log back in.

If that doesn't work, I recommend you stick with Ambiance or Radiance.